# How to access my 127.0.0.1:8000 from Android tablet

Tags: python, android, django, localhost

I am developing a webpage in Django (on my pc with Windows 7) and now I need to test some pages in tablet pcs. Suddenly the thought came if I can have an access to my localhost in Windows from Android tablet. Is that possible? I am in the same Wi-Fi connection in both devices at home.

I have samsung tab 2 10.1 with Android 4.0.4.

Comment: You can't access 127.0.0.1 from a different box.  You will need to make sure your site is listening on your networked address on  your LAN and not just localhost.

Comment: @Joe, so i need to start my localhost with 0000 instead 8000?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 (will listen on all interfaces). There is no need to change the port. But your server must already be doing that for you. Did you try accessing via the wireless-interface's ip (and port 8000)?

Comment: Also, check firewall.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find out what the ip address of your PC is with the `ipconfig` command in a Windows command prompt.  Since you mentioned them being connected over WiFi look for the IP address of the wireless adapter.

Since the tablet is also in this same WiFi network, you can just type that address into your tablet's browser, with the :8000 appended to it and it should pull up the page.

Comment: are you positive your web server is running correctly?  If you type 127.0.0.1:8000 into your PC browser does it show up?

Comment: i solved the issue with starting my server with specific ip. ``/manage.py runserver 193.140.209.49:8000``

Comment: Have you tried viewing the page from another computer? One which  is not the tablet?  If it works from another computer but not from the tablet that helps to isolate where the problem is.  If it also does not work from another computer, it could be a firewall setting on your Windows PC.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning, for future reference, that port forwarding is one of the options to try as well, and the firewall on the PC hosting the server should be disabled while doing this. That way, the phone can actually connect, otherwise it will display an endless loading page, and then fail due to connection timeout

Answer (score 36):

So, there are a couple of issues it seems. The question most of the answers are addressing is "how do you connect to another server in your local network?" (or variants). There are two answers, you can use the computer's IP directly, or you can use the computer's name (you may need to append `.local`). For example, my computer is `xavier.local`.

The second issue is that you seem to be addressing is that `runserver` is not accessible via other computers on the network (this is your *actual* question). The reason is that by default Django's runserver will only acknowledge requests from the machine which is calling them. This means that the default settings would make it so that you would only be able to access the server from Windows (and they did this on purpose for security reasons). In order for it to listen to other requests you have two options:

```
runserver 192.168.1.101:8000 
# Only handle requests which are made to the IP address 192.168.1.101
```

Or (and this is easier when dealing with more than one environment):

```
runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 # handle all requests
```

So, if your IP address is 192.168.1.101:

```
runserver # only requests made on the machine will be handled
runserver 127.0.0.1 # only requests made on the machine will be handled
runserver 192.168.1.101 # handles all requests (unless IP changes)
runserver 192.168.1.100 # does not handle any requests (wrong IP)
runserver 0.0.0.0 # handles all requests (even if the IP changes)
```

---

I do think it important to note that `0.0.0.0` is realistically not a security question when dealing with a local, development machine. It only becomes a significant problem when working on a large app with a machine which can be addressed from the outside world. Unless you have port forwarding (I do), or something wonky like that, you should not be too concerned.

Comment: after using `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` I still cant access the server from an android phone. Accessing 192.168.1.101:8000 directly from the dev machine (the one hosting the server) works though. I am on Max OSX El Captain

Comment: `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` worked for me only after adding the IP address of my PC to the allowed hosts in Django's `settings.py`.

Comment: @Anupam did you find any work around for your problem? I'm also having same issue.

Comment: @Eswar if I remember correctly, it did work but intermittently. I think I used `runserver 0:8000` and modified `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` to get it to work.

Answer (score 26):

Though this thread was active quite a long time ago. This is what worked for me on windows 10. Posting it in details. Might be helpful for the newbies like me.

1. Add `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` in django `settings.py` file
2. run django server with `python manage.py 0.0.0.0:YOUR_PORT`. I used `9595` as my port.
3. Make firewall to allow access on that port:

   - Navigate to **control panel** -> **system and Security** -> **Windows Defender Firewall**
   - Open **Advanced Settings**, select **Inbound Rules** then right click on it and then select **New Rule**
   - Select **Port**, hit next, input the port you used (in my case `9595`), hit next, select **allow the connections**
   - hit next again then give it a name and hit next for the last time.
4. Now find the ip address of your PC.

   - Open **Command Promt** as adminstrator and run `ipconfig` command.
   - You may find more than one ip addresses. As I'm connected through wifi I took the one under *Wireless LAN adapter WiFi*. In my case it was `192.168.0.100`
   - Note that this ip may change when you reconnect to the network. So you need to check it again then.
5. Now from another device (pc, mobile, tablet etc.) connected to the same network go to `ip_address:YOUR_PORT` (in my case `192.168.0.100:9595`)

   Hopefully you'll be good to go !

Comment: Incredible answer !

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It _almost_ worked for me, I can see my phone tryin to load it, but it unfortunately gets stuck and doesnt load. I followed your proceedur exactly, confused why it isn't working

Comment: @amy did you find solution?

Comment: @cikatomo This was almost 2 years ago. I remember I did manage to get it working in the end but can't remember if it was this specific solution or slight modification - sorry I couldn't give you a definitive answer

Comment: @amy thank, I couldn't make it work normally, but I've found simple mitmproxy tool which acts like reverse proxy

Comment: I just want to correct number 2 to add **runserver** to be **python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:YOUR_PORT**.

Answer (score 6):

`127.0.0.1` is a loopback address that means, roughly, "this device"; your PC and your android tablet are separate devices, so each of them has its own `127.0.0.1`.  In other words, if you try to go to `127.0.0.1` on your Android tab, it's trying to connect to a webserver on the Android device, which is not what you want.

However, you should be able to connect over the wifi.  On your windows box, open a command prompt and execute `ipconfig`.  Somewhere in the output should be your windows box's address, probably `192.168.1.100` or something similar.  You tablet should be able to see the Django server at that address.

Answer (score 2):

need to know the ip address of your machine .. 
Make sure both of your machines (tablet and computer) connected to same network

192.168.0.22 - say your machine address

do this :

192.168.0.22:8000   -- from your tablet

this is it !!!

Comment: this solution doesn't work. The browser freeze. You need to specify a ip address

Answer (score 1):

If both are connected to the same network, all you need to do is provide the IP address of your server (in your network) in your Android app.

Comment: you mean, 127.0.0.1:8000 ?

Comment: No, 127.0.0.1 cannot be accessed from another device.. IP address of your machine on your network. You can get it using ipconfig or ifconfig.

Comment: this solution doesn't work, at least with me. Although, if I specific do manage.py runserver <mymachine ip>:myport works

Answer (score 0):

Tested using easy EasyPHP DevServer 14.1.
The trick is you must first add your local ip address to the Apache server to listen to it.

Right click on the tray icon, go to "Configuration" -> "Apache" in the "httpd.config"

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.168.0.201:80  <<-- ADD THIS LINE
```

Then go to your Control Panel and deactivate your Windows Firewall or add your Smartphone/Tablet Ip Address to the exception.

That's it. I hope it helps.

The IP Address 192.168.0.201 may be different from yours. 192.168.0.X

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this problem myself, and I couldn't figure out what it was, since it worked perfectly on my iPhone, I decided to look into the problem and find a quick solution.
My local machine is a Mac OSX 10.10+, one option would have been to start an Apache server, but that's super unhandy - changing the DocumentRoot every time you want to check something quickly on your Android device. Besides that, changing the DocumentRoot is a pain in the a** on Mac OSX 10.10.

If you want to use:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

on your Android, do this:

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer [ANY PORT YOU WANT, BUT NOT 8000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
python manage.py runserver 
then connect both tablet and system to same wifi and browse in the address
eg: python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.100:8000
In tablet type that url in adress bar

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was required to disconnect and reconnect to the same network (both phone and pc), after changing the firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @foysal, but I had Visual studio code and python Forbidden in inbound rules, so I marked them available for all connections

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on android and emulator and this is how i solved it

**1)** Make sure run server on 0.0.0.0
this make accessible on emulator and android devices

> in terminal: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
>
> in PyCharm: `edit configuration -> put 0.0.0.0 in Host`

**2)** Find PC IP address with `ipconfig` command and copy IPV4
[image]

**3)** Add ipv4 to ALLOWED_HOST in django `settings.py`

**4)** IF YOU USE WINDOW make sure disable windows defender firewall

[image: disable windows defender firewall]

**5)** double check that your computer and your device(mobile) using the same WIFI