# Accessing django localhost server through lan

Tags: android, python, django, networking

I have a django server running on my PC. I want to access the server through my android phone.How can I do that? I tried running

> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000.

After this, I can access server from my pc through PC's ip address, but not accessible through other device coonected to same wifi.

Comment: did you check to see if you have a firewall running on your pc?

Comment: Yes, I have firewall running on my pc but I enabled incoming connection for python.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewall completely?

Comment: Creating a mobile hotspot solved my issue, I was (naively) trying to make it work on a hotel wifi

Comment: check this answer and see if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76603982/6401241

Answer (score 19):

you need to do these steps

```
1. run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
2. figure out your ip address which is say 192.168.1.8
3. Add '192.168.1.8' to ALLOWED_HOSTS list in your settings.py file.
4. access 192.168.1.8:8000 on mobile.
```

I tried this, its working for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped. :) But it seems this site: http://whatismyip.host/ is giving a wrong ip4 address so i turned to ipconfig. and there i got the correct one.

Comment: whatismyip.host should ideally be giving you the public ip, for this you need the private ip adress, which is your local ip.

Comment: So silly of me. I got it after giving it some thought and I was planing to delete my previous comment but now I found your reply which maybe helpful for future readers so I am not gonna delete it. Thanks again bro. Happy coding. :D

Answer (score 5):

can you try it `python manage.py runserver youripadress:8000` [`python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.1:8000`]

Comment: Thanks buddy. For those who are still struggling type ipconfig in your cmd and under `Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:` locate your IP4 Address.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal run

`ipconfig`

and find the **IPv4 address**
,and if you are using Django go to **settings.py** and in the **ALLOWED_HOST** add the **IPv4 address** in the list.

In my case

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.30.81', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '192.168.167.206']
```

then run ( in my case )

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.167.206:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

A related issue I ran into was in relation to this error:

"code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\***\***\***\***\***\***\***\***\***')
[time stamp] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP"

Just verify that this is the reason you are not able to view also. Of course you would see this in your server messages if so.