# is there a way to load django website on mobile device during development?

Tags: django, mobile

I want to see what the website would look like on mobile web browsers during development like I could at localhost in the desktop web browser. Is there any way I could do that? Thanks!

Comment: I think this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116718/how-to-access-my-127-0-0-18000-from-android-tablet

Answer (score 0):

you can run your server with this code:

```
python manage.py runserver xxx.xxx.x.x:8000
```

for example 192.168.1.20:8000

you should write your ip address instead of xs

also google chrome's inspect view has this feature, you can open inspect page with ctrl+shift+I and press ctrl+shift+M to change your view to mobile.